# Laravel eloquent returning SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1815 Internal error: JSON wrapper: unexpected type after upgrading Aurora mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

We had a query (select * from users where id IN ()) that due to an Amazon Aurora bug was causing a restart of the DB instance so Amazon support suggested an upgrade from Aurora MySQL version 3.02.2 with MySQL 8.0.23 to Aurora version 3.03.1 with MySQL 8.0.26.

Once the upgrade was done the restart issue disappeared but still the query is causing an error on the endpoint:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException · SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1815 Internal error: JSON wrapper: unexpected type (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` in (<id-of-the-users>) and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Related code:

```
// Retrieve public chat messages with sender information $publicMessages = $webinar->webinarChatMessages() ->where('type', WebinarChatMessage::TYPE_MESSAGE) ->with(['sender']) ->whereNull('recipient_id') ->orderBy('webinar_chat_messages.id', 'asc') ->get();
```

Same error on another endpoint for this query:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException · SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1815 Internal error: JSON wrapper: unexpected type (SQL: select * from `users` where `stripe_customer_ref` = cus_test and `users`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

Related code:

```
$user = UserWN::where('stripe_customer_ref', $json['customer'])->get()->last();
```

I tried to run the same queries directly on the database and I didn't get any errors so I suppose it's related to Laravel Eloquent.

Comment: how did you upgrade?

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:php] and [tag:laravel]? If that's relevant to the question, your code should be included, as well as stack trace and the actual query that's causing a problem. The environment you're running in is almost certainly irrelevant, unless you have good reason to think it's part of the problem.

Comment: Are you *certain* that the Laravel app is pointing to the same database?  Since running the queries on the database directly does not raise the error, maybe the Laravel app is using the wrong hostname..

Comment: @nbk I've upgrade from AWS rds dashboard:
References:
[1] Upgrading the minor version or patch level of an Aurora MySQL DB cluster - Upgrading Aurora MySQL by modifying the engine version - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.Patching.html#AuroraMySQL.Updates.Patching.ModifyEngineVersion

Comment: @miken32 I've asked also in laracast forum and it seems indeed related to laravel https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/laravel-eloquent-returning-sqlstatehy000-general-error-1815-internal-error-json-wrapper-unexpected-type-after-upgrading-aurora-mysql. I think the environment it's part of the problem because I have staging environment with the same codebase but different aurora serverless version and it isn't thworing the same error.

Comment: @miken32 Anyway, here is the code involved:
First query:
// Retrieve public chat messages with sender information
        $publicMessages = $webinar->webinarChatMessages()
            ->where('type', WebinarChatMessage::TYPE_MESSAGE)
            ->with(['sender'])
            ->whereNull('recipient_id')
            ->orderBy('webinar_chat_messages.id', 'asc')
            ->get();

Second query:
$user = UserWN::where('stripe_customer_ref', $json['customer'])->get()->last();

Comment: @billrichards yes I'm 100% sure the Laravel app is pointing to the same database.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant information. Using `toSql()` instead of `get()` will show you the query. Including the migration definition might also be of some use.

Comment: @miken32 this is the query that I got for the second query/method by running it with "to Sql()" instead of get(): "select * from `users` where `stripe_customer_ref` = ? and `users`.`deleted_at` is null"

It's the same reported in the error. Anyway can't share the entire migration definition but I can share with you the last field that we added on the users table that is, indeed a json:

Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->json('subscription_json')->nullable();
        });

According to the response of the bot in laracast forum it's probably related